# Find command in vim gets incomplete path

Tags: vim

In vim when I'm using :find to open another file, it misses the first component of the relative path.

For example, if I'm looking for a file that's in:

```
./foo/bar/file.txt
```

I'll type

```
:find **/file.txt
```

It finds the file but then tries to open

```
bar/file.txt
```

It works correctly if I type

```
./**/file.txt
```

But I'm lazy and don't want to type that much. Is there some config I'm missing that will correctly locate and open this path?

### My Solution

I simply appended the main source code dir to my path

```
exec "set path^=src/**"
```

Comment: Which version of Vim are you using? I'm having trouble reproducing your results in Vim version 7.3.

Comment: For your problem about it trying to open the wrong file, do you have `autochdir` set?  (That caused all sorts of havoc for me so I instead have an autocmd to do `lcd %:p:h` on `BufEnter`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `'path'` set?  That (IMO) is a pretty handy way to keep from even typing the `**/` bit.

In my setup, there's an environment variable that defines which project I'm currently in so I use that and construct a path with that as the root.  In a nutshell:

```
let s:rootdir = $PROJECT_DIR
let s:path = 'src/**;' . s:rootdir . ',scripts/**;' . s:rootdir
execute "set path=" . s:path
```

Then I can just `:find a_file.txt` and it searches my src hierarchy then my scripts hierarchy for the file.